# DataSource reflected after maximizing the window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is really peculiar. I tried a simple data binding example program. I tried to bind a collection (IList) to a list box. When i alter the collection, the list box is updated only if i maximize the window. Here are the snippets,

```
<ListBox x:Name="myBirthdaysListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UniformGrid>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                <Label Content="{Binding DateOfBirth}"></Label>
            </UniformGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myCalendar = new List<Calendar>();
    myBirthdaysListBox.DataContext = myCalendar;
}
```

I am just a beginner in wpf. Kindly let me know, if i have done some thing terribly wrong in here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `BindingList<Calendar>` rather than just a `List<Calendar>`, As binding list raises events for when items get added/removed/etc.

What you're seeing is the control is redrawing when you resize, and it's going through all the data again.

Off the top of my head, I believe you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Calendar` such that the binding list is notified if an item in it changes

Comment: Yep, this seems to work (i replaced the list with BindingList). If i would like to stick on to the list, should my Calendar class inherit the INotifyPropertyChanged interface ?? I tried doing so, it has no effect. Can you explain me why ?

Comment: What does your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged look like?

Comment: if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateOfBirth")); } I added this to the constructor of the Calendar class as its the only place from where you can set the values of the fields. So i am raising PropertyChanged for both the fields

Comment: I'd expect the event to be raised during change of the properties (after all, that's what the event represents). The BindingList<> will listen for this event, and raise the appropriate event for the control to listen to (this is why you'd use BindingList<> rather than List<>, as the controls are looking for an implementation of IBindingList, which List<> doesn't